# Как образовано слово "качели"?

Tags: словообразование

Понятно, что от слова "качать", но откуда суффикс -ел'? Это тот самый суффикс, что и в словах: метель, гибель и т.п.? Но почему тогда нет в литературном языке слова "качели" в единственном числе? Только простореч. "качеля"/"качель", но это не норма.

В словаре Даля в статье "качать": "Качель ж. морская болезнь, головокруженье и рвота от качки. Качель ж. качели мн. качуля ж. перм. гугали арх. устройство разн. рода, для качанья ради забавы, увеселенья."

Comment: Есть еще слово "качалка". Здесь "а" сохраняется, никакой "е" - нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

качать-качель-качели -суффиксальный, как и гибель, купель, метель

Слово "качель" в ед. числе существовало и в значении "качка", и в знач."качели", видимо, под влиянием слова карусель(заимств.из франц. саrоussеl ,) :Блок:"убаюкан качелью снов", Грин :"метало «Эспаньолу», как качель", Лесков - "не позволяла снять качель",  есть у Мандельштама и Цветаевой .   В 17-томном академическом «Словаре русского литературного языка» (1948 – 1965) это слово ещё присутствует. С пометой  устар. А потом стало употребляться во мн.ч., как и остальные "парные": ворота, штаны,брюки, очки. У качелей же две опоры, так что всё правильно с точки зрения семантики. Карусель -одиночный предмет(кстати, когда-то было муж. рода: конный карусель), качели - парный.